# Can't create new properties in CoreData subclass? iOS8 Swift3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, ios8

I've created a Data Model in Xcode, selected all my entities, clicked in Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass. It created all the +CoreDataProperties and +CoreDataClass in the scope of my workspace, not my project.

I then proceeded to edit the class files as follows:

```
public class Child: NSManagedObject {
    enum Gender:Int{
        case male=0,female,unknown
    }

    var uuid:UUID = UUID()
    var gender:Gender?

    convenience init(name:String,birthday:String,gender:Int){
        self.init()
        self.name = name
        self.birthday = Conversor.convertDate(dateString: birthday)
        if(gender >= 0 && gender <= 2){
            self.gender = Gender(rawValue: gender)!
        }
    }

    func setGender(gender:Int){
        self.gender = Gender(rawValue: gender)!
    }
    func setBirthday(birthday:Date?){
        self.birthday = birthday
    }
}
```

I didn't touch the Properties files.
Everywhere I learned about CoreData told me that the class files are not generated again by Xcode and that they were safe to edit but there is a comment in the file that tells me the opposite

```
//  This file was automatically generated and should not be edited.
```

When I try to use the class in my project the autocomplete can't find the gender and uuid and if I try to use it it says:

```
'Gender is not a member type of 'Child'
```

Among many other errors of this kind

There is no reference of those files in the project Build Phases

What is the correct way of doing this?
How can I edit the CoreData class so that I can have other properties and methods that has nothing to do with CoreData?

Thank you very much in advance
:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please select code generation for your entity in right panel to Manual/None. and then proceed to click in Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. I did it, it still created in the workspace scope. Now it can't find the Child in the project. It says "Use of undeclared type 'Child'

Comment: After cleaning and restarting Xcode it worked perfectly. Thank you very much!